# Rails: Set sort number to rearrange table items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, haml

I've got a table, consisting of individual table rows for each entry (spark session). Currently, spark sessions are indexed to order by `created_at` in a descending order.

[image: example photo]

I am trying to extend the ability to enter a sort number and order the spark sessions based on their sort number.

*i.e Setting the sort number on `Spark Session for iOS users (archived)` to `1` would move that spark session to the top of the list.*

I would need to make a migration to `add_sort_number_to_spark_sessions` as an integer, allow a user to input a sort number into the view from a `text_field`, save that order and reload the page to display the new sort.

What functionality do I need to allow the sort number to be inputted in the view, saved to the database and reflected in the display order for the view?

*Index View*

```
- @spark_sessions.each do |tbl|
    %tr
      %td.bold.nudge-text-link-black
        = link_to tbl.name, edit_spark_session_path(tbl)
      %td= link_to 'Edit Sparks', spark_session_sparks_path(tbl), :class => 'float-right nudge-secondary-button'
```

*Controller*

```
def index
    @spark_sessions = @company.spark_sessions.where(is_archived: false).order('created_at desc')
  end
```

Comment: What work have you done already to try to complete this?

Comment: That 'Edit Sparks` button should take you to the `edit` view which is implemented in `edit.html.erb` most likely. You can add a field to that view to support the new sort column.

Comment: @DiegoSalazar Good thinking, in the `index` view I can display the sort number and let the user set the sort number in the `edit` view. I was trying to let the user manipulate the sort number directly into the index view but maybe that is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement drag and drop sorting on in the index view: http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/ajax-sortable-lists-rails-4